# ASUS TUF Gaming FX505dt doesn't reliably turn on

Tags: boot, laptop, power, shutdown, asus

I'm facing some issues for a couple of weeks. Sometimes when I try to power on my laptop and press the power button the keyboard backlit turns on and the diplay also turns on but before showing anything it goes off. But on the second try, it turns on. Not every time I face this issue. But most of the time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware problem, which cannot be diagnosed over
the internet.

The only advice we can give is to run any diagnostics that may have
come with your BIOS, or any that came with your computer,
or that may be found on the website of the computer manufacturer.

You may also run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight,
which tests memory and more.

If nothing is clearly indicated, take the computer to a repair-shop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the laptop ASUS FX505 did not boot from battery without charger, it turned on it showed the asus logo it started windows and turned off immediately but if I connected the charger the keyboard flashed and it started fine, it was a battery problem. Once started with charger it could be disconnected and work on battery fine but not start only with it without charger

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).